# Не получается решить задачу "Тренировки" на С++ с шагами

Tags: c++, комбинаторика, олимпиада

Задача

Тренер хочет, чтобы спортсмены из его команды взбежали по ступенькам стадиона, используя большие (2 ступеньки) и малые (1 ступенька) шаги следующим образом:

Количество больших шагов, сделанных каждой ногой спортсмена, было одинаково;
Количество малых шагов, сделанных каждой ногой спортсмена, было одинаково;
Количество больших шагов должно быть не меньше количества малых шагов;
Спортсмен начинает шагать с левой ноги.
Напишите программу, которая поможет тренеру определить, сколькими способами спортсмены могут подняться по ступенькам стадиона по заданным им правилам, если она состоит из n ступенек (n – четное).

Например, при n=6 существуют 4 таких способа:

2**2**1**1**, 2**1**1**2**, 1**2**2**1**, 1**1**2**2** (жирным выделены шаги, которые спортсмены делают правой ногой)

Вход: файл input.txt, в единственной строке содержится четное число N.

Ограничения: 0

Выход: файл output.txt, в единственной строке содержится количество способов, которыми спортсмены могут подняться по ступенькам стадиона.

input.txt
2
6
output.txt
0
4

Я подумал, что написать, что если 2 шага, то 0, если 4 шага, то 2**2**, то есть 1, если 6, то 4, если 8, то 2**2**2**2** и меняя местами правые и левые шаги всего 6 способов. Что дальше не знаю и как записать тоже(

Comment: а ограничение какое на число ступенек? Так-то тут формула простая есть.

Comment: А да забыл про ограничение. Ограничения: 0<N<101. N - количество ступенек

Comment: ну тогда проблема в чём? тупо перебором можно... Делите наполам, перебираем число 2 (не больше 25 штук будет) остальные - 1. Добавляем к ответу (C[n-k,k])^2 ну и всё...

Comment: Павел ты ведь спортивный программист, можешь дать совет начинающему спортивному программисту?

Comment: А что означает формула (C[n-k,k])^2 ?

Comment: число неупорядоченных сочетаний без повторений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде так?

Перебираем все варианты решения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

L - большие шаги, S - маленькие

Для каждого набора L,S получаем способов расставить их для одной ноги -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для каждой левой перебираем все правые, итого - возведение в квадрат. Так что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где сумма берется по всем решениям приведенной выше системы уравнений.

Для `N=6`: есть только одно решение `L=1, S=1`, откуда ответ - 4.

Для `N=12`: есть два решения `L=3, S=0` и `L=2, S=2`, откуда ответ - 37. Выписывать долго, но похоже на правду :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long term(unsigned long long L,unsigned long long S)
{
    unsigned long long N;
    if (L < S)
    {
        N = L; L = S; S = N;
    }
    N = 1;
    for(unsigned long long K = L+1; K <= L+S; ++K)
        N *= K;
    for(unsigned long long K = 2; K <= S; ++K)
        N /= K;
    return N*N;

}

unsigned long long total(unsigned long long N)
{
    unsigned long long Sum = 0;

    for(unsigned long long L = N/6; L <= N/4; ++L)
    {
        unsigned long long S = N/2 - 2*L;
        if (L < S) continue; // Паранойя...
        Sum += term(L,S);
    }
    return Sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int n = 2; n <= 100; n+=2)
        cout << setw(4) << n << "   " << setw(20) << total(n) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Да, только мне надо, чтобы значение было в исходном файле и выводить в другой файл ( я сам сделаю), но все вы круто С++ знаете

Comment: @Max Блин, как мед - так ложкой?! А самому хоть что-то сделать? А то ну точно как тот мужик, что ребенка тонущего спас... Через несколько дней звонок в дверь. Открывает - стоит женщина. Это, мол, вы моего ребенка третьего дня вытащили из реки? - Ну, я, да не стоит благодарности... - Какой, нафиг, благодарности?!! на ребенке шапочка была - где она?!??!!!! :)

Comment: я и говорю, что сам сам доделаю)